# A list of objects get lost after a new session is created

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I often have a list of objects displayed for browsing purpose or management purpose in my application. The user search through a database and gets a list of objects based on his request.

I want to know if there's a secure way to make these list of objects survive a new session. As far as I've read, in ASP.NET MVC, when a new session is created (either because a redirect was made or a new class is created, whatever the reason), static variables or similar data structure (ex: Session["listObjects"]) gets their values emptied because of the new session.

That's a problem because I would like to avoid registering things in the database at best because there's no need at this point. I often have to make up to 5 or 6 different calls before submitting any changes to the database, and sometimes this creates new entries **but** I still need to display the old listing and it gets flushed meanwhile.

So is there any way to make data survive a new session or being persistent other than storing them in a database?

Comment: cache the object list is another option instead of storing them in session..use NCache for instance.

Comment: Are you caching information in session information that really is common for all users?

Comment: Well I don't know how caching works. I'm exploring this right now. It's common data, something quite simple (ex: a list of items for an e-commerce), I just want this data to remain "alive" longer than a session might allow it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make data survive a new session or being persistent other than storing them in a database?

Well, you could save the data in a file, but how easy that is depends on your structure.  Is your data contained in one class that can be persisted in XML to a file?

You could also:

- Use config settings (which can be changed) if the data doesn't change often (and isn't user-specific)
- Use the registry (which doesn't scale across servers)

Comment: you mean serialize the list into Json or XML...?

Comment: Either - XML is more standard for file storage while JSON is more standard for cross-process communication.  Neither is wrong.

Comment: That makes me think, I could use some sort of cookie?

Comment: cookie idea is bad. cookie will be passed on each request between server and forth and cookie size is 256K MAX...

Comment: Ok, nice comment. Right now I'm exploring the caching method, I've never done that. Could it be an option?

Comment: If this is user-specific data and you don't care if/when they clear cookies that _may_ work, but it puts a lot out your control that you need to account for.  Plus the acceptance of cookies is optional in most browsers, so what do you do if they don't want to accept cookies?

Comment: Yeah, good point. The objective is rather to keep the data alive during a longer period of time than a session, so that's why I asked my question.

Comment: I'll explore caching, but if you have any info on both, I'd appreciate.

Comment: @DStanley Both options you present seems a bit overload for the intended purpose, isn't it?

Comment: @HerveS You have to persist somewhere - Session (and Cache, which uses Session) don't last forever.

Comment: @Shaz NCache uses Session - I wouldn't use it as "persistent" storage.

Comment: Seems like caching data also rest upon a session, and when the session is flushed or created anew, the caching is also gone...

Comment: @HerveS that is correct.  Cache is designed to last a _shorter_ time than session.

Comment: Ok, I'll try writing the whole thing in a temporary XML file.

Answer (score 1):

How are you retrieving the list of objects? Could you store the parameters in a [Query String?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, maybe, but then I'd end up having the same kind of problem, the query string might get flushed because of the new state, no?

Comment: No, that's what's nice about it. When a user redirects, variables can be stored in the url's query string for fetching later. It's a way of sharing data between pages/sessions.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example in c# of how I could do that?

Comment: Sure. Let's say you have two pages, page1.aspx and page2.aspx. In page1, you might have something like: String pg1Key = textBox1.Text. if you wanted to retrieve what this key was set to in page2, you could put a redirect in page1 like: Response.Redirect("page2.aspx?key=" + pg1Key). Then, in page2, you would get the key using this: String pg2key = Request.QueryString("key").

Comment: I should also add that it's not limited to just one variable, you can add multiple to a QueryString.